# Javascript print not working with css changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print html content using below code in jQuery

```
function printTable() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("tblTranscript");
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Page</title>');
    newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>');
    newWin.document.write('</head><body>');
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}

$('#print').on('click', function() {
    printTable();
})
```

It shows the above table in print preview but css changes are not applied on table. I tried different combinations for css href path. I am able to access the css file directly through browser but somehow it isn't showing while printing.

Comment: If you use CSS print media, there is no reason to need to use a pop up window.

Comment: You need a printable CSS ... bootstrap isn't printable 

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.printItn = function(myID) {
    'use strict';
    var printContent = document.getElementById(myID),
        windowUrl = 'about:blank',
        uniqueName = new Date(),
        windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime(),
        stylesheet = $('body').data('theme'),
        WinPrint;

    WinPrint = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=300,top=300,right=500,bottom=500,width=1000,height=500');
    WinPrint.document.write('<' + 'html' + '><head><style type="text/css">@import "' + stylesheet + '";</style></head><' + 'body style="background:none !important"' + '>');
    WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.write('<' + '/body' + '><' + '/html' + '>');
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
};

$(".print").on('click', function() {
    printItn('YOUR-ID');
    return false;
});
```

This works for me

Comment: stylesheet is coming as undefined

Comment: you need to change stylesheet file url 
`stylesheet = $('body').data('theme')`, like `stylesheet = 'http://example.com/assets/print.css'`

Comment: changed it.. still not working . Do I need to add print media in stylesheet ?

Comment: this line, what you changed - is stylesheet. In this file you need to add specific styles for print viewport